# Sitecore Forms with NextJs and Hybrid SSG + SSR rendering

Tags: sitecore-forms, nextjs, jss-forms

I am new to Sitecore JSS and am trying to the implement Sitecore Forms using the hybrid rendering approach [SSR+SSG] in a Sitecore 10.2 with NextJs app. Some selected paths would be SSR rendered and rest of the site will be SSG. I looked at the below links for this:

1. [How could we apply Hybrid (SSG and SSR) rendering with Sitecore Nextjs](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/32800/how-could-we-apply-hybrid-ssg-and-ssr-rendering-with-sitecore-nextjs)
2. https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/20/sitecore-headless-development/implement-a-sitecore-form-in-a-jss-next-js-app.html
3. https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/20/sitecore-headless-development/prerendering-methods-and-data-fetching-strategies-in-jss-next-js-apps.html

And I am following the below approach:

1. Created folders at src/pages/path1 & src/pages/path2 locations
2. Copied the file from https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/blob/release/19.0.0/samples/nextjs/src/pages/%5B%5B...path%5D%5D.SSR.tsx in these folders.
3. Rename the copied file to [[...path]].tsx  to catch all routes under the above paths.
   Now, I am getting the 404 page response when trying to open any subpage under the paths.
   However, I am getting the correct response if I remove the new routes and make the whole app SSR, that means, in the root [[...path]].tsx file.

Could anyone give me an example of doing this or let me know where I am going wrong?

Comment: Go with a different forms solution. Don't use sitecore forms in headless.

Answer (score 0):

As you have not mentioned how your implementation looks like, I cannot provide you a solution but you can check that you have pages created under the Sitecore tree with the same name as you have created under the Next's pages folder. The `sitecorePagePropsFactory` will look for same name in the Sitecore tree. For example, if you have created have something similar in your `src/pages`

```
/pages
  /posts
    /[[...path]].tsx
  /blogs
    /[[...path]].tsx
```

it expects the Sitecore tree to look like

```
/home
  /posts
   /postA
   /postB
  /blogs
   /blogA
   /blogB
```